# jQuery Dialog, passing html to dialog

Tags: 6, forms, javascript

I am looking for a method to pass html to jquery dialog. Without success.

I try:

```
Drupal.jqui_dialog.html(messages);
```

And

```
        Drupal.jqui_dialog.open({
              data : messages
        });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the jQuery UI library with dialog activated on your site, you should be able to do

```
$('<div>' + message + '</div>').dialog();
```